# xml element, unkown name but known it's no complextype

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

So im trying to validate a xml that look like this:

```
<module name="example" alias="ex1">
<params>
    <p1>1</p1>
    <pcomplex>
        <p>2</p>
    </pcomplex>
    <foo>2</foo>
    <bar>3</bar>
    .....
    <pn>this is the n'th element</pn>
</params>
```

pcomplex block should throw an error because i don't want to allow any `complexTye` inside params sequence

I have tried this with this xsd:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="module">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="params" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="alias" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But it fails at what im attempting to do.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in XSD 1.0. However, XSD 1.1 can handle this scenario quite easily. Below is a possible approach: @test is checking for elements with nested elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xsd:element name="module">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="params">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                            
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:assert test="not(*[*|@*])"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>  
</xsd:schema>
```

If you want to allow for a complex type with simple content (i.e. no nested elements, attributes allowed) then simply change the test to `not(*[*])`

An invalid XML may yield this (based on the above schema):

> cvc-assertion.3.13.4.1: Assertion evaluation ('not(*[*|@*])') for element 'params' with type '#anonymous' did not succeed.